# How to correctly perform join but with math operations in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

Here I have a collection, say `test`, storing data with a field named `timestamp` (in ms). Documents in this collection are densely inserted with `timestamp` interval 60000. That's to say, I can always find one and only one document whose `timestamp` is 1 minute before that of a refered one (except for the very first one, of course). Now I want to perform a join to correlate each document with that whose `timestamp` is 1 minute before. I've tried this aggregation:

```
...
$lookup : {
  from: 'test',
  let : { lastTimestamp: '$timestamp'-60000 },
  pipeline : [
    {$match : {timestamp:'$timestamp'}}
  ],
  as: 'lastObjArr'
},
...
```

which intends to find the array of the very document and set it as the value of key `lastObjArr`. But in fact `lastObjArr` is always an empty one. What happend?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `$lookup` pipeline is incomplete as it's missing the necessary math operators. For a start, `lastObjArr` is empty due to a number of factors, one of them being that the expression

```
let : { lastTimestamp: '$timestamp'-60000 },
```

doesn't evaluate correctly, it needs to use the [`$subtract`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/subtract/) operator

```
let : { lastTimestamp: { $subtract: ['$timestamp', 60000] } },
```

Also, the `$match` pipeline step needs to use the [`$expr`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/expr/) operator together with [`$eq`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/eq/) for the query to work, i.e.

```
$lookup : {
  from: 'test',
  let : { lastTimestamp: { $subtract: ['$timestamp', 60000] } },
  pipeline : [
    { $match : { 
      $expr: { $eq: ['$timestamp', '$$lastTimestamp'] }
    } }
  ],
  as: 'lastObjArr'
}
```

Comment: Thanks! I've got a knowledge about math operators. But I cannot understand the `$expr` operator for now... Since [equality match demo](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/#equality-match) in mongodb documents tells me that `$match` could be as simple as a query sentence. Can you explain a bit more?

Answer (score 0):

you defined a variable called "lastTimestamp" and you assign it with

> '$timestamp'-60000
> But you never use it, change your code as following it should work:

```
$lookup : {
  from: 'test',
  let : { lastTimestamp: '$timestamp'-60000 },
  pipeline : [
    {$match : {timestamp:'$$lastTimestamp'}}
  ],
  as: 'lastObjArr'
},
```

Comment: I don't think `let: { lastTimestamp: '$timestamp'-60000 }` works. Should be `let: { lastTimestamp: {$subtract: ['$timestamp', 60000]} }`